# c++ string types confusion

Tags: c++, string, winapi, unicode

I include following files in my .cpp program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Nevertheless, when I write

```
LPCTSTR pMsg;
DWORD msgLen;
...
msgLen = _tcslen(pMsg);
```

The compiler prompts the following error:

> C2664: 'size_t strlen(const char *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'LPCTSTR' to 'const char *'
>   Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast,
>   C-style cast or function-style cast

Of course I can easily fix the problem by casting to `LPCSTR` or using `wcslen`. But that's not right, shouldn't compiler decide all that stuff itself, depending on macro `UNICODE`? It's certainly defined, because when i write `#define UNICODE` in the beginning of the file, compiler prompts the warning, saying that it's already defined. What is the problem then? Why it chooses `strlen` instead of `wcslen`?

Here is the actual code:

```
BOOL PrintString(HANDLE hOut, ...)
{
    DWORD msgLen, count;
    LPCTSTR pMsg;
    va_list pMsgList;
    va_start(pMsgList, hOut);
    while((pMsg = va_arg(pMsgList, LPCTSTR)) != NULL)
    {
        msgLen = _tcslen(pMsg);
        if(!WriteConsole(hOut, pMsg, msgLen, &count, NULL) && !WriteFile(hOut, pMsg, msgLen*sizeof(TCHAR), &count, NULL))
        {
            va_end(pMsgList);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    va_end(pMsgList);
    return TRUE;
}
```

I tried both, `#define _UNICODE` and `#define _UNICODE` but neither didn't help. Moreover, `#define _UNICODE` prompts the warning that it's already defined.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx), the controlling macro is `_UNICODE`, not `UNICODE`. Do you have this defined correctly?

Comment: yes, i tried defining `UNICODE` and/or `_UNICODE` in the beginning of the .cpp file but it didn't help

Comment: Do you ever plan to use MBCS or SBCS? If not, you could just get rid of the whole tchar business and use `wchar_t` explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN, what `_tcslen` expands to is controlled by the macro [`_UNICODE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx). `LPCTSTR`, on the other hand, is controlled by [`UNICODE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Make sure you have these two macros defined consistently, and before any header which might use them is included.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze Does your VS project setting (in Project Properties) have unicode in it as well?

Comment: `before any header` << that really did the trick. I was defining _UNICODE just after includes. but why is that necessary? shouldn't these headers define it themselves?

Comment: @Nika Simply stop using tchar and all your problems go away

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze How could they?? The purpose of this macro is to let you *choose* whether you want to use SBCS, MBCS or UTF-16. The headers look at the state of the controlling macros and define the typedefs and function macros accordingly.

Comment: @David you suggest explicitly using wide characters and related functions related to them?

Comment: Pardon me, I'm quite new to windows API and I'm not used to having ten functions doing roughly the same but with subtle differences I can't always notice. Could you be more specific? Or recommend any good reading on the subject?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. You are tying yourself in knots to write code that can compile for win9x and WinNT. You'll never do the former. The net result is epic confusion for no gain.

Comment: Quite simple. Remove TCHAR. Be explicit about types. So use wchar_t. Define `UNICODE`. End of story. This is my advice from my answer.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze While the primary purpose of that document is slightly different, you might want to read [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/), or at least the section "How to do text on Windows."

Comment: @Angew Isn't it advisable to add _UNICODE and UNICODE in preprocessor settings i.e  Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor ?

Comment: @SmartDev Yes, I would do that, and set the "Character set" option (or whatever it's called) in project properties to unicode as well.

Comment: Don't even bother using data types and APIs that are dependent on `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` to begin with.  Replace `LPTSTR` with `LPWSTR`, `_tcslen()` with `wcslen()` (or `lstrlenW()`), `WriteConsole()` with `WriteConsoleW()`, etc...

Answer (score 2):

`_tcslen` is expanding to `strlen`. `LPCTSTR` is expanding to `const wchar_t*`. This implies that you have `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` defined inconsistently. The former is used by the `TCHAR` header file, the latter by the Windows header file. Given your updated question, I'd say you have `UNICODE` defined and `_UNICODE` not defined.

Beyond that, you should make your life much easier by not using `TCHAR`. That was useful when you needed to be able to compile a single source code for Win9x and WinNT. Nowadays you are presumably not targeting Win9x. So my advice is to simply remove all use of `TCHAR` and make you code much simpler.